# Why isn't the xml text editor's outline view aware of Android's schema?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

When editing my XML layout from within the text editor and right click on an element in the outline view, I'd expect to see the permitted children types in the context menu just as I do when I use autocomplete within the XML text editor.

Is this just not yet supported, or do I have to somehow configure a schema?

[image: Outline editor add child context menu]

Answer (score 1):

The outline view is aware of the schema when viewing the graphical layout.  Right clicking doesn't allow you to choose from valid children to add, but dragging invalid elements from the palette to the outline view will show an "invalid" icon.  Dragging and dropping valid elements places children within the dropped element.

My guess is that the adt developers don't expect users to use the outline view from within the text view to add new elements.  They probably expect users to instead switch to the graphical view and add elements right from the graphical representation rather than the text.

[image: Outline view from graphical editor]

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask... why did you ask the question, if you answered it yourself few minutes later? Or did you just find out?

Comment: @Ahmad this is [encouraged behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/151771) by the SO community.  Not that it matters, but yes I did just figure it out as I was posing the question.  And that happens to me frequently.

Comment: ah ok I see. You answer most of your questions yourself to help  others who search for this particular answer, right?  cool, I like that. Keep up the good work! :)